# Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated SWI-Prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, instantiation-error

I trying to write a Prolog script that can create a list of strings that would after a simple procedure result in a given string. My knowledge of Prolog is very limited and I am not sure it is even able to perform this, so please tell me if it's impossible.

I got this so far

```
replace_word(Old, New, Orig, Replaced) :-
    atomic_list_concat(Split, Old, Orig),
    atomic_list_concat(Split, New, Replaced).
```

It can perform this operation

```
10 ?- replace_word('a','e','glava',X).
X = gleve.
```

But it cannot backtrack it

```
11 ?- replace_word('a','e',X,'gleve').
ERROR: atomic_list_concat/3: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

I can imagine what causes the problem, but is there a way around it?

Answer (score 1):

Sure there should be other options in implementing this, and I'm not a Prolog expert, but it seems that `atomic_list_concat/3` won't accept two variables as arguments (given what this predicate does it would be tricky, right?), so you can bypass the problem with being given a variable by changing the order of the clauses to "fix" the variables that you know before. For example:

```
replace_word(Old, New, Orig, Replaced) :-
    (var(Orig), !, atomic_list_concat(Split, New, Replaced),
     atomic_list_concat(Split, Old, Orig)) ;
    (atomic_list_concat(Split, Old, Orig),
     atomic_list_concat(Split, New, Replaced)).
```

Note that the cut is not necessary, but now you can do what you ask for:

```
?- replace_word('a','e',X,'gleve').
X = glava.

?- replace_word('a','e','glava',Y).
Y = gleve.
```

Comment: The problem is I require _every_ X that can result in 'gleve', this includes 'gleve','glave','gleva' and 'glava'

Comment: @Diego Sevilla: The cut is necessary unless you use `nonvar(Orig)` in the alternative. But it is probably better to use an if-then-else.

Answer (score 1):

replace_word/4 was written that way for efficiency, due to SWI-Prolog first class handling of atoms. To 'reverse' its semantic, I can't see a better way than using an helper predicate:

```
replace_word(Old, New, Orig, Replaced) :-
    (   var(Orig)
    ->  atomic_list_concat(L, New, Replaced),
        insert_alt(L, [Old, New], L1),
        atomic_list_concat(L1, Orig)
    ;   atomic_list_concat(L, Old, Orig),
        atomic_list_concat(L, New, Replaced)
    ).
insert_alt([A,B|R], Ks, [A,K|T]) :-
    member(K, Ks),
    insert_alt([B|R], Ks, T).
insert_alt([A], _Ks, [A]).
```

insert_alt/3 it's a bit more general than required, instead of a list (Ks) the pair of Old-New could be used....

test:

```
?- replace_word('a','e',X,'gleve').
X = glava ;
X = glave ;
X = gleva ;
X = gleve ;
false.
```